# Another UnicodeEncodeError when mixing integers and unicode

Tags: python, unicode, openpyxl

My code:

```
import openpyxl

file_location = "test.xlsx"

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_location, use_iterators=True)
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Blad1")

count = 1
rows_count = sheet.max_row

while count < rows_count:
    print sheet["C" + str(count)].value + " " + str(sheet["D" + str(count)].value) + " " + str(sheet["E" + str(count)].value) + " " + sheet["F" + str(count)].value
    count = count + 1
```

I'm trying to read a .xlsx file. Everything prints out fine until I get to a cell where there is the character "Ä" as well as numbers and I get this error.

```
print sheet["C" + str(count)].value + " " + str(sheet["D" + str(count)].value) + " " + str(sheet["E" + str(count)].value) + " " + sheet["F" + str(count)].value
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc4' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I think I know what the problem is but I have no idea how to solve it. I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: Rather then using str() method you can use encode()

Comment: Are you using Python 3 or Python 2? (Edit: It seems to be Python 2)

Comment: @propeller if it is unicode error then it is python 2.x :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I just removed the str() and everything worked fine! Thanks for everyone who tried to help though!

Answer (score 0):

This id due to the fact "Ä" is not handled by `ASCII` character sets

The `str()` tries to convert it into `ASCII` character so error is thrown instead try `encode()` and "Ä" is handled by `utf-8` and so use that method

```
a=u"Ä"

a
u'\xc4'

str(a)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-368-202e444820fd> in <module>()
----> 1 str(a)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc4' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128) 

a.encode("utf-8")
'\xc3\x84'

print a.encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: @propeller he is not using `str()` only for `count`  see this `str(sheet["D" + str(count)].value)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in that you are passing unicode strings to print statement.

Try something like this:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(): # let openpyxl worry about rows
    print " ".join(cell.value.encode("utf-8") for cell in row[3:7])
```

Comment: Isn't the problem that they are passing a unicode string to the *str function*?

Comment: Possibly. It's pretty unreadable code that isn't encouraged by the documentation that's why I've provided a stub implementation that should be easier to work with.

Answer (score -1):

Try using str.encode() instead of str().

```
myString.encode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')
```

Comment: You might want to lookup the definition of UTF-8. It's encoding specifically designed to be able to represent unicode codepoints.